# Swift : How to get value from completionHandler

Tags: ios, swift

```
func getMac(_ session: String, _ kitcode: String) -> String {
    var mac: String = ""
    api.get_kit(session,kitcode) { resDevice in
        var m: String = ""
        for obj in resDevice {
            if obj.type == 1 {
                m = obj.mac
                break
            }
        }
        print("M : " + m)
        mac = m
    }
    return mac
}
```

**I need to get `var m` to return func**

help me please.

I want to explain more, but I'm not good at languages.

Comment: You cant return variable from an `aync` block like this. `get_kit` is `async` call or `sync` call?

Comment: use a completion handler.

Comment: @adev  `get_kit` is `sync` call

Comment: I doubt it is `sync` call. Then your code should work fine. It should be `async` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options

### 1) pass closure as your function parameter

```
func getMac(_ session: String, _ kitcode: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    api.get_kit(session,kitcode) { resDevice in
        var mac: String = ""
        for obj in resDevice {
            if obj.type == 1 {
                mac = obj.mac
                break
            }
        }
        print("M : " + mac)
        completion(mac)
    }
}
```

#### usage:

```
getMac("session", "kitcode")  { mac in
    print(mac)
}
```

---

### 2) Synchronize

#### 2.1) General

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
var text = "Some text" 

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
    sleep(5)
    text = "Some other text"
    semaphore.signal()
}

print(text) // "Some text\n"
_ = semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
print(text) // "Some other text\n"
```

#### 2.2) Alamofire

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
let request = Alamofire.request("https://someAlamofireRequest.url/")
var text = "Some text"    

request.response(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default)) { _ in
    text = "Some other text"
    semaphore.signal()
}

print(text) // "Some text\n"
_ = semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
print(text) // "Some other text\n"
```

Comment: will you have example for Synchronize api request ?

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski I followed method 2 and it stopped.

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski Thank you very much, but it still stopped.

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski Synchronize api request method is not correct application hung after `_ = semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)` this line, please fix this

Comment: @VarunNaharia I've updated my answer. I hope that now there will be no doubt with semaphores

Answer (score 1):

You have to use block to get the value

```
 func getMac(_ session: String, _ kitcode: String, successHandler: @escaping (_ success:String) -> Void) {
        var mac: String = ""
        api.get_kit(session,kitcode) { resDevice in
            var m: String = ""
            for obj in resDevice {
                if obj.type == 1 {
                    m = obj.mac
                    break
                }
            }
            print("M : " + m)
            mac = m
            successHandler(mac)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 func getMac(_ session: String, _ kitcode: String, completion:(_ value: String) -> Void)
{
    api.get_kit(session,kitcode) { resDevice in
        var mac: String = ""
        for obj in resDevice {
            if obj.type == 1 {
                mac = obj.mac
                break
            }
        }
        print("M : " + mac)
        completion(mac)
    }
```

use as this function

```
  getMac("yourstring", "yourstring", completion:  { (value) -> () in
        print(value)
    })
```