# DispatchGroup [weak self] handling in nested notify

Tags: swift, swift3, grand-central-dispatch, weak-references, blockingqueue

I have two asynchronous functions. I need to run second function based on first's output and run third function after second is complete. I did it like this. Is it correct way to handle serialization? And how to handle weak self reference?

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

dispatchGroup.enter()
function1() // async completion contains leave()

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [weak self] in
    guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
    strongSelf.dispatchGroup.enter()    
    strongSelf.function2() // Also async, dependent on the result of function1. contains leave()

    strongSelf.dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        strongSelf????.function3()
        print("results of function1 and function2")
        // I must wait to finish first two tasks in order, in other words serial queue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1) Correct way to: call the method after the previous one has completed

```
class SomeAsyncType {

    typealias SomeResultType = String

    func async(_ someDate: Any, completion: @escaping (SomeResultType) -> Void) {
        self.asyncfunctionA(someDate, completion: completion)
    }

    private func asyncfunctionA(_ someDate: Any, completion: @escaping (SomeResultType) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            sleep(1)
            print("ResultA")
            self?.asyncfunctionB("ResultA", completion: completion)
        }
    }

    private func asyncfunctionB(_ someDate: Any, completion: @escaping (SomeResultType) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            sleep(2)
            print("ResultB")
            self?.asyncfunctionC("ResultB", completion: completion)
        }
    }

    private func asyncfunctionC(_ someDate: Any, completion: @escaping (SomeResultType) -> Void) {
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
            sleep(3)
            print("ResultC")
            completion("")
            print("All completed")
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### usage:

```
let test = SomeAsyncType() // hold reference 
test.async("noDate") { result in
    print(result)
}
```

#### console:

```
ResultA
ResultB
ResultC

All completed
```

### 2) how to handle weak self reference?

This is new scope then you can use `[weak self]` again

```
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [weak self] in
    guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
    strongSelf.dispatchGroup.enter()
    strongSelf.function2() // Also async, dependent on the result of function1. contains leave()

    strongSelf.dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [weak self] in
        guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
        strongSelf.function3()
        print("results of function1 and function2")
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought so. Is it correct way of handling async functions? I want to keep function calls separate for example keep reverseGeocode separately returning before I start call to next function to use geo result. And when second call is complete, run third to just print results. How to achieve that? I tried serial DispatchQueue sync/async, but in all cases reverseGeo is returning result at the last

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Is it possible to do this without completion handler? For example, serialQueue.sync/async { function1}, serialQueue.sync/async { function2}, serialQueue.sync/async { function3}? Still result of function1 with reverseGeocode comes at the last. DispatchQueue is confusing.

Comment: @JimH. Look my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45475347/6756852

Answer (score 0):

It depends what's your function1 and 2 is but i would consider make it with completionHandlerInstead:

```
function1(completionHandler: { [weak self] results in
   guard let strongSelf = self else {return} 

   if results == true //if it'd be bool
   {
      strongSelf.function2(completionHandler: { [weak self] results in
   guard let strongSelf = self else {return}

      //here you can get results from both if you want
      })
   }
   else
   {
   //false
   }
})
```

Comment: with completion handler I can put second function in first's completion and third function in seconds' completion to avoid DispatchGroup at all. I wanted to keep function calls separate for example keep reverseGeocode separately returning before I start call to next function to use geo result. And when second call is done, run third to just print results. How to achieve that? I tried serial DispatchQueue sync/async, but in all cases reverseGeo is returning result at the last.

Comment: serialQueue.sync { function1}, serialQueue.sync { function2}, serialQueue.sync { function3}, Still result of function1 with reverseGeocode comes at the last